# Significance of perpendicular line being shortest distance between a dot and line?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

When I was 11 my maths teacher used the word perpendicular which I didn't understand so asked what it was. He then tried to make me figure out and he drew a diagram and I said is it the shortest distance possible. He seemed impressed and asked whether I had read that somewhere and didn't believe me when I told him I hadn't. Was he being encouraging (I'm 15 now so can handle that) or is there greater significance than I can think of at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave an another definition of a perpendicular drawn from a point to a line . That's why your teacher must have got impressed as you hadn't read it earlier. And this property can be used for proving many theorems